# When calculating a summation will there be a difference in answer if the index of summation is 0 or 1?

Tags: summation

When calculating a summation will there be a difference in answer if the index of summation is 0 or 1?

There was a question, have forgotten but when i = 1, the whole sum was equal to 15, and when i = 0, the sum was equal to 16.

Who closed this question? I promise this question will help many peoples.

Comment: $\sum_{i=0}^{15}1 = 16$, $\sum_{i=1}^{15}1 = 16$

Comment: @jameselmore Seems to me your second sum is of $15$ terms each $1,$ so wouldn't that be $15$ not $16$ which you wrote?

Comment: You are correct - typo. Thanks. Not giving me the option to edit ...
Should read: $\sum_{i=0}^{15}1 = 16$, $\sum_{i=1}^{15}1 = 15$

Comment: @jameselmore I think when fixed your example would be good to include, as an example of what OP said "There was a question, I have forgotten...". Probably too late to edit original comment but could be recommented...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $$\sum_{i=0}^n a_i=a_0+\sum_{i=1}^n a_i=a_0+a_1+\sum_{i=2}^n a_i =\ldots$$
hence $\sum_{i=0}^n a_i=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i$ if and only if $a_0=0$.

(The same holds with convergent series, i.e., $\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i=\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i$ if and only if either $a_0=0$)